# add'l quesion to Installing Ubuntu Into a Virtual Machine.

Tags: virtualbox

I have followed all of the proceedures listed in the aforementiond answers to this question with some success. Only, Everytime I boot up the VM, it asks me to either Try Ubuntu or Install it. Why can I not simply work on the system? I've started installing it only to cancel out and seem to be able to work with it some there, but still, this seems wrong/broken. Any Help Please??

Comment: Did you create / use a virtual hard disk, and complete installing Ubuntu to it? Your comment "* I've started installing it only to cancel out*" suggests you didn't actually install it yet, and as janos suspects are still booting from the iso

Answer (score 1):

When you installed the Virtual Machine,
you must have set the CD drive to use the ISO image of the installer.
Even after the Virtual Machine is fully installed,
if that setting for the CD drive is still there,
the VM will try to boot from the CD drive first instead of the virtual hard disk.

Edit the settings of the virtual machine,
review the configuration of the CD drive,
and remove the ISO image from it.